# Trigger after update ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write a oracle sql trigger that updates one value on the table after an insert or update. I have to check if the value is 0 and if it is then to set this value to NULL. When I compile the trigger everything is ok but when I need to update the table it says that the table is mutating. I've put pragma autonomous_transaction but when I update it return 'ORA-01422 exact fetch return more than requested number of rows'. I made a before trigger that works but I want to write after update or insert.I tried to use INSERT INTO instead of UPDATE but it return ORA-01400.Is there any chance to write it with AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE trigger or it must be BEFORE That's my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
i NUMBER;
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
SELECT col1 INTO i FROM table1;

IF i = 0 THEN
  UPDATE table1 SET col1 = 0;
END IF;

 END;
```

Comment: Привет. Am I right assuming, you just need to not allow users to insert zeroes or update to zeroes? I mean whenever a user inserts or updates to zero, the new value has to be null?

Comment: Is it possible `SELECT INTO` statement returns more than 1 row? It should only return one row because of the "INTO" clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I made a before trigger that works but I want to write after update or insert.

You cannot use an `AFTER` trigger as the value has already been entered into the table and you cannot modify the entered value in an `AFTER` trigger.

You need to use a `BEFORE` trigger and use the `:NEW` record (rather than trying to select the value from the table):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.col1 = 0 THEN
    :NEW.col1 := NULL;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bmaSPnOD)